# Command to copy files to directory but only the ones that are not already there or have changed

Tags: batch-file, cmd, copy-paste

I remember using a command to put in cmd (or in a bat file) to copy all files from a certain directory (like xcopy) but only copy the ones that have changed or are not yet present in the target directory (not like xcopy). But i forgot the name. Anyone that knows?

I'm guessing it compares the last changed date on the files since checking if they're completely the same would make this rather useless.

It would be used in a batch file to copy some folders into my dropbox but i still want to work inside the folders, not in the dropbox map.

Comment: Yeah that's it :) thnx!

Comment: robocopy "source" "destination" /E /ZB /X /PURGE /COPYALL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
robocopy "source" "destination" /E /ZB /X /PURGE /COPYALL
```

/E :: copy subdirectories, including Empty ones.

/ZB :: use restartable mode; if access denied use Backup mode.

/COPYALL :: COPY ALL file info (equivalent to /COPY:DATSOU).

/PURGE :: delete dest files/dirs that no longer exist in source.

/X :: report all eXtra files, not just those selected.

Comment: Thanks! Less things to look up ^^